# how to perform multi substitution with sed on a block of text?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, pattern-matching

I have text file, and in it has a block that has pattern like below:

```
# cat file
Jit .... enabled=false
Jit ..shoes.. From=2021-01-01
Jit ..gloves.. From=2021-01-01
```

so I want to change all of these matching regex, wrote a sed file with these lines.

```
# cat sedfile
/^Jit/ {

    s/enabled=false/enabled=true/g
    s/From=\d+-\d+-\d+/From=2021-02-01/g
}
```

Pattern `/^Jit/` greps lines only starting with **Jit** and other steps do substitutions.
Date can be anything, so I can't hardcode these, therefore matching a pattern is required.

Desired Ouput:

```
Jit .... enabled=false
Jit ..shoes.. From=2021-01-01
Jit ..gloves.. From=2021-01-01
```

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity apology, I made corrections

Comment: Thanks! It seems that you wouldn't need the greedy `g` flag, since you are performing one substitution per line. What should be the desired output?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity global is required, because there are plenty date patterns and all, but I can solve it's complexity, if I get to be sure that pattern is workin with sed substitution, right now it isn't.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and show us an example that accurately represents your file. If there can be more than one date per line, that is a completely different situation.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with your existing solution? The sed script you show should work well if you replace the `\d` with `[0-9]` since `sed` doesn't understand `\d`.

Comment: @terdon ok I updated. [...] symbolizes more text actually, and it doesn't matter in my scenario.

Comment: It always matters. What if you have the word `not-enabled=true`? Should that be changed? But anyway, since you still  only show one pattern per line, it looks like you don't need `g` which is only useful if you want to make multiple substitutions on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed doesn't know about `\d`. Just use the standard `[0-9]` character class instead:

```
$ cat sedfile
/^Jit/ {

    s/enabled=false/enabled=true/
    s/From=[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/From=2021-02-01/
}
```

Then you can do:

```
line1
Jit .... enabled=false
Jit .... From=2021-01-01
line4

$ sed -Ef sedfile file
line1
Jit .... enabled=true
Jit .... From=2021-02-01
line4
```

Or, without a script file:

```
$ sed -E '/^Jit/{s/enabled=false/enabled=true/; s/From=[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/From=2021-02-01/}' file
line1
Jit .... enabled=true
Jit .... From=2021-01-01
line4
```

I removed the `g` modifier since you only seem to have one occurrence of the pattern per line.

Comment: Ok amigo, you did not update date regex in oneliner.

Comment: Whoops. Sorry @Sollosa, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution assuming (until more comprehensive sample input) that the lines have strict end patterns. If that's the case it wouldn't be necessary more complex matching.

```bsh
/^Jit/{
  s/false$/true/
  s/[0-9\-]\+$/2021-02-01/
}'
```

Output:

```
Jit .... enabled=true
Jit .... From=2021-02-01
```

About the removed `g` flag, see [@terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671903/338177).