# how to invoke sed from awk while following logfile?

Tags: awk, sed, logs, tail

I'm supposed to follow a logfile, I want to initiate a `sed` command to edit conffile upon appearance of certain line in the log. I did little research and found out that it can be done with `awk`.

and the syntax is like:

```
tail -f /path/to/serverLog | awk '
                    /Printer is on fire!/ { system("shutdown -h now") }
                    /new USB high speed/  { system("echo \"New USB\" | mail admin") }'
```

as proposed in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12075/best-way-to-follow-a-log-and-execute-a-command-when-some-text-appears-in-the-log)

so I wrote my own like with a `sed` variant:

```
tail -f logfile | awk '/^Jit ended**/  { system("sed -E '/^Jit/{s/enabled=false/enabled=true/; s/From=[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/From=2021-02-01/}' conffile") }'
```

but it doesn't work, and throws errors like

```
(^ syntax error|^ unterminated string)
```

I guess this is to do something with `{}` in the `sed` command not getting compatible with `awk` syntax, but no idea where exactly, and how to get it work.

Comment: You are trying to use a single-quoted string constant (the `sed` expression) inside a single-quoted string constant (the `awk` program) ... that won't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Whatever you want to do with `sed` from `awk` can most likely be done in `awk` directly.

Comment: you might also want to read [Why does awk do full buffering when reading from a pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33650/72456).

Comment: @AdminBee ok but I want to add changes into file. So what's the way to do if not with sed?

Comment: [GNU Awk manual (sub, gsub, gensub)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) do replacement.

Comment: @they please if you can propose a method

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity actually I want to do in-place substitution, and logfile following is necessary, so can you suggest any alternate?

Comment: GNU awk has `-i inplace`, just like GNU sed has `-i` but awk is a tool to manipulate text while a shell is the tool to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to commands - you're trying to use awk as if it was a shell, don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling awk to call other commands you're doing:

```
shell { awk { system { subshell { cmd } } } }
```

instead of simply

```
shell { cmd }
```

which is very inefficient and fragile.

Best I can tell you should just be doing something like (untested):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
        *"Printer is on fire!"* ) shutdown -h now ;;
        *"new USB high speed"* )  echo 'New USB' | mail admin ;;
        "Jit ended"* )            tmp=$(mktemp) &&
                                  sed 's/foo/bar/' conffile > "$tmp" &&
                                  mv -- "$tmp" conffile
                                  ;;
    esac
    sleep 1
done < '/path/to/serverLog'
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, this code seems promising, but it looks like input redirection only reads logfile single time, whereas I need it to follow logfile, till it finds required occurence of the text.

Comment: @Sollosa There is nothing stopping you from piping `tail -f logfile` into the loop instead of reading from the log with a redirection.

Comment: @they I'm using this syntax, `done < <(tail -f logfile)` but it's not reading logfile instead it throws syntax error

Comment: @Sollosa Possibly because you are running the script with the wrong interpreter (`sh` instead of `bash`?). In any case, why don't you try what you used in the question and what I alluded to when I suggested piping the input from `tail`, i.e. `tail -f logfile | while ...; do ...; done`

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNU `awk's` replacement function `sub`, given the sample input from your [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671899/how-to-perform-multi-substitution-with-sed-on-a-block-of-text), and using the [inplace extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html) to write the file (always do a backup before executing your command):

```
$ cat conffile
Jit .... enabled=false
Jit ..shoes.. From=2021-01-01
Jit ..gloves.. From=2021-01-01
```

```bsh
$ tail -f logfile | while IFS= read -r i; do 
  if echo "$i" | grep '^Jit'; then
    awk -i inplace '/^Jit/ { sub(/=false$/, "=true"); sub(/[0-9\-]+$/, "2021-02-01"); print  }' conffile
    exit # exit if a match is found
  fi
done
```

```
$ cat conffile
Jit .... enabled=true
Jit ..shoes.. From=2021-02-01
Jit ..gloves.. From=2021-02-01
```

I should add my commentary from [my answer to that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671907/338177) regarding the substitution:

> I propose a solution assuming (until more comprehensive sample input) that the lines have strict end patterns. If that's the case it wouldn't be necessary more complex matching.

And a note: I'm using `grep` because I'm not savvy enough with `awk`, I'm sure other answers will be much better (and this one criticized or corrected), but maybe you can get a glimpse of what you can do.

Comment: Ok I have centos7, and it seems `-i` is not an option in it. Any workaround?

Comment: @Sollosa it seems that you [can install `gawk`](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/gawk-4.0.2-4.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm.html) in centos, it should work by I'm not sure.